# Can a start a Twilio Conference via API or through a runtime function?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I'm building a Conference Call moderation console (in Salesforce). There will be many attendees joining a conference, either by dialing in or by our outbound autocalling. There will also be up to 3 moderators joining.

The client does NOT want the conference to start automatically when the moderators enter. Rather, they want it on a button to "Start Conference". From the docs, I see how to start the conference when a moderator joins (startConferenceOnEnter), but can't find any instructions where I can just HTTP POST or use a Twilio runtime function to start the conference. Am I missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't, however you could use handle this in different ways. Maybe one way is to [enqueue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue) people up and once the button is pressed, drain the [queue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/member-resource) into a conference.

Maybe another way is to have then all dial into the conference with `startConferenceOnEnter` set to false. Then create an automated leg that dials in the conference with `startConferenceOnEnter` set to true using the [REST API /Calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource). Then you can remove that participant once the conference is started.

Probably some other ways to accomplish the same goal, but those are the first two that came to mind.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your thoughts on alternatives. I was thinking about hold, but queue might be better... I'll take a look.

Comment: The queue is limited to 100 people and I'll have more than that, so I think I need to put them on hold. There doesn't appear to be a way to put them on hold as I'm adding them to the conference. Oh... maybe a .then that takes their CallSid and holds them.

Comment: I thought of a better way... put all participants into the conference startOnEnter = false. Put the Moderator(s) into a "backstage" conference, then when they press the button have them enter the main conference startOnEnter=true. Much easier.